# Filter an array of objects based on multiple search terms

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search, parameters

Say I have a search term, `const searchTerms = ['sarasota', 'fl']`

And a list of locations,

```
const selectedRestaurants = [{
  city: "Orlando",
  name: "Dons Food Place",
  state: "FL",
  id: 1
},
{
  city: "Sarasota",
  name: "Rons World",
  state: "FL",
  id: 2
}]
```

If I search 'Sarasota FL', I want to only return the one Sarasota FL location. But if I'm searching based on multiple parameters (City and State) the search returns both locations, because it matches the state during my second iteration.
EDIT: I also need this to work when I search only 'Sarasota'

Here is my code:

```
filterBySearchTerm(searchTerms) {
   let searchedRestaurants = [];

      for (var j = 0; j < selectedRestaurants.length; j++) {
        searchTerms.forEach(term => {
          if (term.toLowerCase() === this.state.selectedRestaurants[j].city.toLowerCase()) {
            searchedRestaurants.push(this.state.selectedRestaurants[j])
          }
          if (term.toLowerCase() === this.state.selectedRestaurants[j].state.toLowerCase()) {
            searchedRestaurants.push(this.state.selectedRestaurants[j])
          }
          if (term.toLowerCase() === this.state.selectedRestaurants[j].name.toLowerCase()) {
            searchedRestaurants.push(this.state.selectedRestaurants[j])
          }
        })
      }

      //I use Set to remove duplicates ^^
      searchedRestaurants = [...new Set(searchedRestaurants)]
      
      return searchedRestaurants;
  }
```

I've been stuck on this for a bit now...can anyone help?
Might not make a difference but I'm in ReactJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const restaurants = [
  {
    city: 'Orlando',
    name: 'Dons Food Place',
    state: 'FL',
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    city: 'Sarasota',
    name: 'Rons World',
    state: 'FL',
    id: 2,
  },
];
const searchTerms = ['sarasota', 'fl'];
const lowerCasedTerms = searchTerms.map((term) => term.toLowerCase());
const params = ['city', 'state'];

const result = restaurants.filter((restaurant) =>
  lowerCasedTerms.every((lowerCasedTerm) =>
    params.some((param) => restaurant[param].toLowerCase().includes(lowerCasedTerm)),
  ),
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const selectedRestaurants = [
  {
    city: "Orlando",
    name: "Dons Food Place",
    state: "FL",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    city: "Sarasota",
    name: "Rons World",
    state: "FL",
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    city: "Sarasota",
    name: "Rons World",
    state: "SL",
    id: 3,
  },
];

function search(searchTerms) {
  let isCity = !!selectedRestaurants.filter((i) =>
    searchTerms.includes(i.city.toLowerCase())
  ).length;

  let isState = !!selectedRestaurants.filter((i) =>
    searchTerms.includes(i.state.toLowerCase())
  ).length;

  return selectedRestaurants.filter((r) => {
    if (isCity && isState) {
      return (
        searchTerms.includes(r.city.toLowerCase()) &&
        searchTerms.includes(r.state.toLowerCase())
      );
    } else {
      return searchTerms.includes(r.city.toLowerCase());
    }
  });

}

// All city match with sarasota
console.log(search( ["sarasota"]));

// All city match with sarasota and state f1
console.log(search( ["sarasota", "fl"]));
```

Comment: This is really close, but now when I search by only one parameter (sarasota) nothing comes up. When I switch the && to ||, it doesn't work for multiple terms like I have in this post.

Comment: @CodySmith in this case it is necessary to know is the filter is based on one attribute or on multiple attributes then we can search it easily, updated ans may help for you

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this approach? It's merging all object values to check if all search terms are included inside it.

```js
const selectedRestaurants = [
  {
    city: "Orlando",
    name: "Dons Food Place",
    state: "FL",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    city: "Sarasota",
    name: "Rons World",
    state: "FL",
    id: 2
  }
];

const searchTerms = ['sarasota', 'fl'];

const foundRestaurants = selectedRestaurants.filter((restaurant) => {
  const valuesAsString = Object.values(restaurant).join(' ').toLowerCase();
  const allTermsMatching = searchTerms
    .map(term => valuesAsString.includes(term.toLowerCase()))
    .every(match => !!match);
  return allTermsMatching;
});

console.log(foundRestaurants);
```